# Perl script - how to calculate how many days and hours between two date and timestamps

Tags: regex, perl, datetime

Perl script - how to calculate how many days and hours between two date and time?

Eg:

Date:2012-10-23T09:49:41.197+0100

To

Date:2012-10-23T09:49:43.838+0100

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.12/lib/DateTime.pm). It takes care of many details for you.

You can then subtract the DateTimes to get a DateTime Duration. Please take a look at the documentation, it is pretty good and clears up some more points about the result.

```
my $duration = $datetime1 - $datetime2;
```

To format a DateTime, one can use strftime, like ( for example ) so:

```
$dt->strftime( "%d days %H hours" );
```

or see [Formatters/Stringification](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.12/lib/DateTime.pm#Formatters_And_Stringification) in the docs.

For DateTime::Duration, I believe you will have to build your own string from the values, it does not stringify like DateTime.

Comment: or you use Time::Piece as in the linked answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Bytepusher, I would like to get the output like x days y hours format?